# How to change default color to Tab Host

Tags: android

I am using 2.2 SDK version. and i used TabHost to display the activity in tab view format. when i install application in mobile phone(Version 2.2.1), the tab host color has been changed into yellow color. Even i dint give any color to TabHost. i dont know why the color has been changed. The same application when i run in emulator, it displays default color(ie) gray and black. can anyone faced and solved this issue pls guide me. Here the code

`

```
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("classA").setContent(new Intent(this, classA.class)));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("two").setIndicator("classB").setContent(new Intent(this, classB.class)));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("three").setIndicator("classC").setContent(new Intent(this, classc.class)));`
```

Comment: it's not issue it's feature ... tabhost using android default theme

Comment: Yes you are right, but whenever i install application in mobile phone, the color has been changed into yellow color.

Comment: so default theme on device isn't yellow ... could you provide TabWidget definition in layout file? and drawable selectors if any

Comment: No i dint give any layout for this.

Comment: so u didn't use setContentView in this activity ? maybe u changed theme in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Yes i dint used SetContentView in this activity. I am not sure i made changes in AndroidMainfeast.xml. let me check. I gave admob ads to my application, is this made any changes to my application...???

Comment: @HariRam What is the default tabs color in your mobile phone (i.e. in other apps)? Are you sure it's not yellow? For instance, in my phone tabs are blue by default while other widgets are black-and-white. And be noticed that tab color is not a solid color. It is a set of drawables (PNG-files), so it's not easy to change tabs appearance, especially accidentally.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In default android tab bar color will be in Grey, you can easily change the color of the tab bar.

Use the below line of code to change the color of Tab

```
     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
or
     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4E4E9C"));
```

For further Reference you can refer [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-%E2%80%93-part-2).

If you are looking for iphonish Tabs you can refer this http://bakhtiyor.com/2009/10/iphonish-tabs/

Comment: Thank you, but what i want to display it in default color, i dint need any other color rather than default color.

Comment: @HariRam: For that you have to put the selector on it. Really nice one. like it. :)