# How to change theme of TabHost from Holo.Light to Dark theme

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-dialog, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere

I have been trying to change the theme for `TabHost`. So far I have got till here:

[image: Light Tabhost Theme]

I have achieved this by using the following xml:

```
<TabHost
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/signupLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

            <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </ScrollView>

            <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </ScrollView>               
        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My `MainActivity.java`:

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(
ActivityMain.this,
android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);

final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) wrapper
    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);                             

dialog = new Dialog(wrapper);
dialog
    .requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog
    .setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

TabHost tabs = (TabHost) dialog
    .findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabs.setup();
tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

TabSpec tspec1 = tabs.newTabSpec("Tab1");
tspec1.setIndicator("SIGN UP");
tspec1.setContent(R.id.scrollView02);
tabs.addTab(tspec1);

TabSpec tspec2 = tabs.newTabSpec("Tab2");
tspec2.setIndicator("LOG IN");
tspec2.setContent(R.id.scrollView01);
tabs.addTab(tspec2);
```

As I'm using `Dialog` class for the view and integrating `TabHost` inside the dialog, that's why I'm using `ContextThemeWrapper` for this to have some theme on the `Dialog`.

Now, my question is that how can I change the `Holo.Light` theme to `Dark` theme. Here is the picture what I want:
[image: Dark theme for tabhost]

I know that android does not have `Holo.Dark` theme as of now. That is only available for `ActionBars`. So how can I achieve this solution.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
//Changing the tabs background color and text color on the tabs
for(int i=0;i<tabs.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) 
{ 
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    TextView tv = (TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); 
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
}
```

And for the indicator, have a layout like this beneath tabwidget

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="#bdbdbd" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_indicator_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#f44b3b" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_indicator_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#bdbdbd" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

And change the background color of indicator like this based on the tab selection.

```
tabindicator1.setBackgroundColor(Color
                            .parseColor("#f44b3b"));
```

Comment: I would suggest keeping the layout resources and code separate. Colors and styling should be defined in the layout files to get a cleaner code.

Answer (score 2):

See the link it will helpful 
[How to change default color to Tab Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754668/how-to-change-default-color-to-tab-host)

and also refer this it will helpful

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using as much of android's source as possible. It really makes things cleaner in my opinion. I added a basic example of what I used below. Not perfect but closer than anything else I was able to fine and cleaner than most examples.
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res

For instance, for the holo theme, use this.
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/tab_indicator_holo.xml
and get all the resources and put them into your project. After that, use the link
http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136
and modify it to work as you want.

Your Layout file

```
<TabHost
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabHost">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
    android:background="#000">
</TabWidget>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</FrameLayout>
```

Code - same as josh clemm

```
        mTabHost=(TabHost)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    //mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);

    setupTab(new TextView(getActivity()), "Tab 1");
    setupTab(new TextView(getActivity()), "Tab 2");
    setupTab(new TextView(getActivity()), "Tab 3");


private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
    TabHost.TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}
    });
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

And then tab_bg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/tabsLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/tab_selector"
          android:padding="10dip" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:id="@+id/tabsText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Title"
          android:textSize="15dip" android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In res/values/styles.xml, change the theme parent to `"android:Theme.Holo"` instead of `"android:Theme.Holo.Light"`

This will change the entire app's theme obviously, but you can also use different styles for different activities.